# Masking a circle and moving the mask with animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, mask

I have a circular div that is vertically and horizontally centered in div. I am trying to achieve a css animation, that it seems like it's fading in from top to bottom.

I thought of making height 0 initially and moving to 50px, however as it is centered, it starts to getting created from the center. Instead, I want to it to get positioned to the initial position and it gets created from top to bottom. Just like there is a square only masking the circle and nothing else, and it moves to down.

```
#circle {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   border-radius: 50px;
}
```

How can I add this a square mask to achieve the below effect?

Please note that background has a gradient, so I can't put a square and assign it a color directly, thus I thought I need to mask them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to achieve this effect?

---

What I have tried:

```
@keyframes example {
   from {height: 0}
   to {height: 80px}
}
```

As the circle is centered, it starts to expand from the middle. This is not what I want. That's why I thought of the mask

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You may have to use either an image background or generate a gradient background for the object. See my answer below.

Comment: "Nants ingonyama bagithi baba
Sithi uhm ingonyama

Nants ingonyama bagithi baba
Sithi uhm ingonyama
Ingonyama" - The Lion King intro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

I am able to achieve this with a combination of a image `background` and `background-position` animation.

This will **not work** if you set the background as a CSS color like `#fff`. it **needs to be an image or a gradient**. You also need to set `background-repeat` to `no-repeat`

The animation simply starts with the background **out** of the div display area then pulls the the background downward into the display area.

Kindly check the examples in full-screen.

**Working snippet (jpeg image as object background):**

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(244, 226, 156, 0) 0%, rgba(59, 41, 58, 1) 100%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(244, 226, 156, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 96, 87, 1) 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 120vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sun {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 100vw;
  margin: 5em auto;
  animation-name: sunrise;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/eVdQ3Q/white.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes sunrise {
  from {
  opacity: 1;
    background-position: 0 -700px;
  }
  to {
  opacity: 1;
    background-position: 0 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sun"></div>
```

**Working snippet (gradient as object background):**

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(244, 226, 156, 0) 0%, rgba(59, 41, 58, 1) 100%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(244, 226, 156, 1) 0%, rgba(130, 96, 87, 1) 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 120vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sun {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 100vw;
  margin: 5em auto;
  animation-name: sunrise;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(white,white);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes sunrise {
  from {
  opacity: 1;
    background-position: 0 -700px;
  }
  to {
  opacity: 1;
    background-position: 0 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sun"></div>
```

Comment: That's pretty neat example! Thanks for sharing! However I needed something like, the circle is white and the background is with gradient. And make it get created from top to bottom. You seem like you know css animations; I'd be grateful if you can suggest me a way! Thanks again

Comment: @senty You're welcome. No, you don't need to explicitly use an image. You can use a gradient as the background for the object. I updated the answer to show both examples. Thank you.